# Does AWS Visibility timeout guarantee that the message is not delivered during that period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

If I set visibility timeout of a message to say 5 minutes, is there any scenario where it can still be delivered to other consumers for processing, before 5 minutes?

Comment: Yes, it's possible - see my answer on related question about [duplication within SQS, and how to reduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38290017/836214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html):

> For standard queues, the visibility timeout isn't a guarantee against
>   receiving a message twice. For more information, see At-Least-Once
>   Delivery.

So no, using a standard queue, you aren't guaranteed that a message won't be processed twice.